# nlohmann-json: add something to json object

Tags: c++, json

I've got this json file:

```
{
     "user1" : {
         "sell" : [
             { "id":1001, "name" : "some name1", "price" : 100, "available" : 10, "category" : "xxx"},
             { "id":1002, "name" : "some name2", "price" : 200, "available" : 10, "category" : "xyz"}
         ],
         "buy" : [
             { "id":2001, "name" : "some name4", "price" : 100, "available" : 10, "category" : "jkdhsajdh"},
             { "id":2002, "name" : "some name7", "price" : 200, "available" : 10, "category" : "dasdasfjk"}
         ]
     },
     "user2" : {
         "sell" : [
             { "id":403049, "name" : "some name1", "price" : 100, "available" : 10, "category" : "xxx"},
             { "id":434432, "name" : "some name2", "price" : 200, "available" : 10, "category" : "xyz"}
         ],
         "buy" : [
             { "id":32144, "name" : "some name4", "price" : 100, "available" : 10, "category" : "jkdhsajdh"},
             { "id":5244, "name" : "some name7", "price" : 200, "available" : 10, "category" : "dasdasfjk"}
         ]
     }
 }
```

and I have no idea how to add some items to let's say data["user1"]["buy"]

```
std::ifstream f(argv[1]);
json data = json::parse(f);
```

so how can I add some stuff to data["user1"]["buy"]?

Comment: Use [push_back](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#stl-like-access)

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/array_t/) says that JSON arrays are represented using `std::vector` by default. Therefore, you can simply use `push_back`.

Of course, you'll first have to pack your data into another JSON object before you push it into the array.

Something like this (untested):

```
json newEntry;
newEntry["id"] = 2003;
newEntry["name"] = "another name";
...

data["user1"]["buy"].push_back(newEntry);
```